# Will a PS3 save work with PS4?

Tags: destiny

So I really like Destiny and I can see myself playing it for quite a while. I'm curious to know that, because it's all 'online' are characters linked to the console or to the PSN account?

Will I be able to level up my Guardian on PS3 and when I eventually buy a PS4, and a copy of Destiny PS4 will my characters still be available?

Comment: If the downvoter wants to leave a comment with suggestions on how I could improve my question, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes. If you get Destiny on a PS4, you will be able to play your character on both the PS3 and PS4. You won't be able to move from Playstation to Xbox, however.

> Just like hopping worlds, you can use the same Guardian on Next Gen and Legacy Gen consoles – so long as you stay in the same system. Ergo, you can move from PlayStation to PlayStation and from Xbox to Xbox, but not across product lines.

[From Bungie](http://www.bungie.net/7_Bungie-Weekly-Update---07182014/en/News/News?aid=11938)

Comment: This is good news! Not sure why my wallet is whimpering.

Comment: Just to clarify. You don't get a copy of your characters on your PS4, they're the same characters, so you can switch back and forth if you like. Great if you have friends on both generations of the console that you want to play with.

Comment: Your characters are hosted on Destiny servers, and are playable within the same brand (PS or XB). I regularly switch back and forth from my 3 and 4 and I lose nothing when doing so.

Comment: If you purchased the game through the PS store on your PS3, you will be able to download it for free on your new PS4 as an already purchased item.