# How do I transfer my Destiny account from Xbox 360 to Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, destiny

I need help getting my account from my Xbox 360 to my Xbox One. I have a level 31 and level 29 guy and I'd not like to start over.

Comment: What email did you not have? (Your question is incomplete)

Comment: Download your profile from Xbox live.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Will a PS3 save work with PS4?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185508/will-a-ps3-save-work-with-ps4). But the short answer is - use same gamertag, and you'll have access to your chars on both systems.

Answer (score 2):

If you sign in on the xbox one with the same gamertag then you will have the same characters, gear and everything. Basically your data is tied to your gamertag on the bungie servers so you don't have to do anything special.

For example a friend who plays on the 360 came round to my house recently and he jsut loaded his gamer profile onto my xbox one. When he then loaded the game he could just see his character without any need to do anything special.

So in summary it just works. :)

Comment: This is confirmed by Bungie on their console transfer FAQ

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Xbox One store and look up Destiny. When you get to the store page it will say start free trial, do that. When you launch the game, it will have an option to import all of your character saves from the Xbox 360.

Answer (score -3):

First go to the store, search Destiny. You will see an INSTALL button, install it and then your ready to go.