# Can I transfer my characters and The Taken King from Xbox 360 to Xbox One?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-one, destiny

I got *Destiny* on Xbox 360 and Xbox One. I was wondering if I can transfer my Xbox 360 characters to Xbox One. I don't have *The Taken King* on Xbox 360 but I do on Xbox One. If I transfer my characters, will I still have The Taken King?

Comment: Related / Possible duplicate of [How do I transfer my Destiny account from Xbox 360 to Xbox One?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/198236/4797)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, transferring your characters does not affect if you have the DLC or not. Since you already have The Taken King on the Xbox One, Transferring your characters from the Xbox 360 to the Xbox One won't change the fact that you still have the DLC on the Xbox One.

Answer (score 0):

**You will not have The Taken King on Xbox One if you transfer.**

To transfer, you need to own Destiny on both, which you've stated you do. When you transfer, your characters and the first two expansions will transfer, but The Taken King is an exception.

> The Digital Upgrade Program is a limited time offer that allows players who bought the Expansion Pass, Expansion I (The Dark Below), or Expansion II (House of Wolves) to upgrade those DLC packs from last generation consoles to a current generation console in the same console family (PlayStation 3 to PlayStation 4; Xbox 360 to Xbox One) for free. **The base Destiny game and the Destiny: The Taken King Expansion are not eligible for this program.** For more information on the Digital Upgrade Program, please see the following link: https://www.destinythegame.com/digital-upgrade

Emphasis mine. [Source](https://www.bungie.net/en/Help/Article/12122)