# Destiny transfer from console to console

Tags: destiny, xbox-one

Am I able to transfer my Destiny character from Xbox One to Xbox One? Cause I want to buy my own console.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Will a PS3 save work with PS4?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185508/will-a-ps3-save-work-with-ps4)

Comment: Not a duplicate, that one asks for switching to the next generation, this one asks if you can do the same without upgrading.

Comment: Yeah, but the same principle applies. Destiny accounts are linked to a network account.

Comment: Do you have your own gamertag or did you create the destiny character on someone elses account? If the former, then yes, simply start the game on another xbox while being logged in. If the latter, then you can't split the character away from that account.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use your same Destiny character on different consoles since it is tied to your GamerTag.

Bungie addressed this in a [Weekly Update](https://www.bungie.net/7_Bungie-Weekly-Update---07182014/en/News/News?aid=11938) from last summer (in the Q&A section):

> According to David Shaw, our self-professed Chief Pyrotechnical Officer, this was the plan all along, as we set out to build an adventure that would span generations. “Our service is built with flexibility in mind. As a player of Destiny, you have a Bungie account that’s bound to your PSN ID or your Xbox LIVE Gamertag, instead of a specific generation of device.”